# Aws lambda, cant run npm module

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules

I am trying to create a AWS Lambda function to merge pdf files stored in S3, and I am getting the following error:

```
    Error: Command failed: java -jar  "/var/task/node_modules/easy-pdf-merge/jar/pdfbox.jar" PDFMerger "samplepdf1.pdf" "samplepdf2.pdf" "merged.pdf"
/bin/sh: java: command not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:607:12)
  killed: false,
  code: 127,
  signal: null,
  cmd:
   'java -jar  "/var/task/node_modules/easy-pdf-merge/jar/pdfbox.jar" PDFMerger "samplepdf1.pdf" "samplepdf2.pdf" "merged.pdf"' }
```

I have installed and saved the npm module locally on windows, zipped it all and uploaded as aws lambda function with the following structure

```
myFunction.zip:
-node_modules
index.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, you're trying to call the java command under a node lambda which is not going to work.

I suggest you create another lambda java function that will accept the pdf files to be merged and return the merged file to your original lambda function

Comment: https://github.com/rse/pdfbox-simple.  This is created for Node and mentions Java being required, which leads to me to think it's possible, are you sure it can't be done?

Comment: This is a Lambda environement not like a normal server environment where you can install binaries there, and not all npm packages especially ones require external binaries can work properly there!